# When to separate Google Analytics properties?

Tags: google-analytics

In the Google Analytics help page
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2649554?hl=en

> Consider your long-term reporting goals and how they might affect your
>   account structure. Create an implementation plan before you set up new
>   properties. In some cases, you may want to have multiple resources all
>   send data to the same property. In other cases, you may want each
>   resource to send data to a separate property. In either case, you can
>   use views and filters to create specific perspectives of your data.

My question is, when should I use separate property and when I should not? What are the cases?

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider:

1. if you are using GA Premium, where you can do enterprise roll-up reporting,  you would require separate source properties to be rolled-up
2. for non-premium, separate properties gives you more flexibility with your custom dimensions and custom metrics (you get 20 per property)
3. a single property with multiple views gives you only 20 CDs and CMs across all your views
4. setting up a roll-up view in a single property requires only your main tracker with specific view filters included
5. with multiple properties, in setting up roll-up reporting, you need a separate property specifically for roll-up reporting.

Comment: Let's say I have desktop, mobile site, ios, and android, which has really similar feature, should I use same properties or not?

Comment: The same property for all of them? No. If you had, say, different web subdomains then I would consider the same property, but you have different platforms and you wouldn't be able to track them all into the same property anyway (web and apps). You need to ask yourself what makes sense in terms of reporting. Without really know much more about your site I would probably createa different property for each web site and app.

Answer (score 0):

First of all get some buffer for knowing what is the traffic on your website.

- after knowing this analyse what people (demographics) like what kind of pages.
- after analyzing this put them in different segments and target them seperately.